How to solve the problem "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation." calling Azure API with a token (Python script)
I am trying to create a script in Python that, using a token that I have obtained thanks to the help of Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token, allows me to authenticate in the Azure portal and be able to make a GET call to obtain the information of one or more users.
I can get the token with a script just providing tenant, client_id and client_secret but then when I call the API with the token, I get an error. This is the piece of code, just the function, that provides me the .json with the info I need:
def call_api_with_token(token, subscription_id, resource_group_name, service_name, user_id):
    url = f"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resource_group_name}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{service_name}/users/{user_id}?api-version=2022-08-01"
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Failed to call API: {response.text}")

I get this error:
Error: {"error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.","innerError":{"date":"2024-04-01T14:40:30","request id":"xxxx","client-request-id":"xxx"}}}

I tried other scripts, I've seen videos and I have this error again and again. Is it maybe because I do need to apply any police or change any API permission for this access via token?

Have you given the app you created for this, corresponding to the client ID, any access to Azure resources? If not, you need to give it sufficient access to the API Management service in question. That may be a built-in role or you may decide to make a custom role. More details at links below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal - in your case you are assigning access to a service principal, but its the same option in the portal.


To call Azure Management API as a service principal, make sure to assign proper RBAC role to it under the required Azure resource.

I registered one Azure AD application and added API permission by granting consent:

In my case, I added Reader role to the above service principal under my Azure APIM resource like this:

To fetch the user by calling Azure Management API, I used below code and got response successfully:
import requests

def get_access_token(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret):
    token_url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token"
    data = {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_secret': client_secret,
        'scope': 'https://management.azure.com/.default'
    }
    response = requests.post(token_url, data=data)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()['access_token']
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Failed to obtain access token: {response.text}")

def call_api_with_token(token, subscription_id, resource_group_name, service_name, user_id):
    url = f"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resource_group_name}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{service_name}/users/{user_id}?api-version=2022-08-01"
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Failed to call API: {response.text}")

def main():
    # Replace placeholders with your actual values
    tenant_id = 'tenantId'
    client_id = 'appId'
    client_secret = 'secret'
    subscription_id = 'subId'
    resource_group_name = 'Sri'
    service_name = 'DemoAPIM0304'
    user_id = 'ID0304'

    token = get_access_token(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)
    user_info = call_api_with_token(token, subscription_id, resource_group_name, service_name, user_id)
    print("User Information:", user_info)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Response:

